# "eventDateTime": on Microsoft Graph Security API alerts response always comes with the same format?

Tags: api, security, graph

"eventDateTime": on Microsoft Graph Security API alerts response always comes with the same format? (2017-12-21T14:30:00.1234567Z)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the alerts will always come with the same format. You can learn more about the Alert schema from the Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/alert?view=graph-rest-1.0